# Adding items to list view with text label and key value

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to add items to a `ListView` control.  I wish to add the items with a text value (which is shown) and a hidden key value that it has when it is selected.

I've tried the following code:

```
string flows_path = "C:\\temp\\Failed Electricity flows\\";
            List<ListViewItem> flows_loaded = new List<ListViewItem>();

            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(flows_path, "*.rcv").Select(Path.GetFileName))
            {
                ListViewItem new_item = new ListViewItem(s, 1);
                ListViewItem.ad

                // Add the flow names to the list
                flows_loaded.Add(new_item);

            }
```

But it tells me that `ListViewItem` doesn't have an overload of `(string, int)` and it doesn't appear to have a 'value', 'text' or 'key' value that I can set.

`ListViewItem("My Item")` works, but I don't know how to implement a key for each item.

Comment: You could use the `Tag` property of every ListViewItem to store and retrieve the key value.

Answer (score 8):

You can store an additional value associated with a ListViewItem by storing it in the `Tag` property.

```
ListViewItem new_item = new ListViewItem(s);
new_item.Tag = my_key_value;
```

ETA: Please remember that the `Tag` property is of type `object`, so in some cases you may need to explicitly cast values to the proper type when retrieving the value.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a "hidden"-value by setting the Tag-Property of the ListViewItem

```
ListViewItem new_item = new ListViewItem(s)
{
   Tag = 1
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  Am I using the wrong control type if I have to use the `Tag`, or is this the correct way to implement this?

Comment: It's the correct way. The Tag-Property you have at each control. There you can save any informations you'll need.